# LPQ on Windows 8 doesn't find my printer

Tags: printing, printers, network-printers, lpr

I have enabled the LPD and LPR on a Windows 8.

I want to print some files using the LPR command, but i can't even find the printer with the LPQ.

I can print normally with the printer through (ctrl + p), but i can't find it with the LPQ command.

```
C:\>lpq -S localhost -P HiTi_P510L

Servidor LPD do WindowsErro: the specified printer doesn't exists.
```

If i try to run the LPR directly i have the same error saying that the printer doesn't exists.

```
C:\>lpr -S 127.0.0.1 -P HiTi_P510L camila.jpg
Erro: o servidor de impressão não aceitou a requisição. Trabalho interrompido.
```

The event log:

```
LPD refused the job \\127.0.0.1\HiTi_P510L because the specified printer doens't exist on this computer.
```

net view:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net view \\myserver
Recursos compartilhados em \\myserver

Nome do compartilhamento  Tipo       Usado como  Comentário

--------------------------------------------------------------
HiTi_P510L                Impressão              P510L
Comando concluído com êxito.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

update: port 515 is listening.

```
C:\>netstat -an

Conexões ativas

Proto  Endereço local         Endereço externo       Estado
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:515            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING 
TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
...
```

I can also telnet localhost 515 which gives me a black screen, and after i press ENTER i have this:

```
☺

Conexão ao host perdida.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: @douglas-anderson, i think firewall is ok. i've updated the question with the netstat -an. i can also telnet localhost 515 which gives me a black screen.

Comment: GREAT. I got some progress. Now i'm able to send files to the printer by typing: lpr -S 192.168.1.6 -P P510L -o raw camila.jpg

Comment: The only problem is that "-o raw" is not working. It's priting a lot of text. Any suggestion?

Comment: I have moved all of my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: There are two issues here.  The answer to the question regarding LPR/LPD is resolved here while the other issue was relating to the actual print stream is answered at the bottom of this response.

Ensure your firewall is off (or at least allowing 515 to pass through).  Also, ensure you are using the IP of your network adapter and not local host as LPD tends to bind to an actual IP address.

If you want to ensure that your data is passed through without modification / encoding then use -o l in the command line.  For example:

```
lpr -S <workstation_ip> -P <printer_share> -o l test.ps
lpr -S 192.168.1.6 -P P510L -o l test.ps
```

Also ensure the file you are sending is actually supported by the print device. While some printers support graphic formats most are expecting PCL, PS, XPS, PDF etc. Some support TIF and other JPG etc.  Ensure the file you are sending is supported by the device.

---

In the end the issue appears to be the proprietary nature of the device and as such, the requirement is there to push the file through the print driver. One simple way is to use a graphics application that supports command line printing.  One option is MS Paint.

```
mspaint /pt IMG_1234.jpg "Hiti P510L"
```

The printer name (Hiti P510L) is the name that appears in the devices and printers screen in Windows.

Comment: nice. you solved my problem, but i cant still print my image.. i think my printer would accept JPG files. it's a HiTi P510L. i tested png, tiff, pdf and PS (generated by ImageMagick) files.  i can see on the queue (when i use ctrl + p) that the file size is about 3mb and the orginal image size is 500kb, so i think something is converting the file automatically, but i have no idea which format. tried right click but no success. any suggestion? i will accept your anwser, im just trying to debug and print the image.

Comment: Using ctrl+p and printing from your application will convert the graphic to whatever format the driver is designed for (likely Postscript). It is common for the size to balloon as it is converting and wrapping the image in another format.  I don't know that device specifically but it's rare that printer would just accept jpeg. In fact, you probably don't want it to as you want to tell it orientation, size etc. which would all be defined by an application and driver.  Pause the print spooler and email me the .spl file in the C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS folder (support@ballisticecho.com)